# WCF Security: Client Login Best Practice

Tags: c#, wcf, security

Users can connect via HTTPS to my WCF service running on an IIS-Server. In order to identify 
the user I have created an alphanumeric user-ID stored in a database.

My plan is to use an asymmetric encryption method, encrypt the user-ID, store it in a file and make it then public to my client. Clients then connect via HTTPS to my WCF service and call Login("Encrypted User-ID").

Is this a good and secure way to realize a client<->service login? And what could I do against stealing the file with the encrypted user-ID? Or should the server running the service issue a certificate for the service which does the authentication? But how could I then store the user-ID in that certificate?

Comment: Why don't you just issue passwords and use any of existing or custom methods for username/password authentication?

Comment: The client application runs in background and I thought it would be more convenient to specify a "login-file" rather than to type username and password everytime they use it...

Comment: @WiktorZychla: You pointed out to a good issue, without the use of password, whatever this system is, it is still pretty insecure

Comment: Any alternative if I don't want the user to interact with the system? I also don't want to store any credentials in a config file etc. I thought if I use a user-file only users in possession of this file can communicate with the server ... but pretty insecure if you ask me

Comment: @libjup: I don't see any difference between the "login-file" and the "login-file-containing-username-and-password-encrypted". You could even encrypt a part of the configuration file so that the sensitive data is protected http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18209/Encrypting-the-app-config-File-for-Windows-Forms-A

Comment: @libjup: "but pretty insecure if you ask me" not if the identity of the client is approved. Digital signature is a mathematical scheme for demonstrating the authenticity of a digital message or document. And the good thing is that you can find it in System.Security.Cryptography

Comment: @CMonster I still don't get if I use a digital signature attackers would still be able to gain access if they could get the certificate file of the client, wouldn't they?

Comment: @libjup: What you mentioned is like when you encrypt something in RSA and you are afraid of the key being stolen and then your data gets compromised. It is just a higher level of security to make sure that requests are coming from the right clients. However the DSA algorithm is pretty complicated, not anyone can mimic the right signature and doing so requires a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of Asymmetric crypto-systems, the performance of your app is gonna suffer a bit since they are proved to be computationally expensive. A good way to keep data in a database encrypted is TrippleDES, the key is three times as strong as DES and can't be cracked easily. In case the data get stolen, the chance that your key gets broken is very low.

To prevent any unauthorized access to critical files you can identify the client using DSA (Digital Signature). So if the client is not identified, then you can reject to allow them to access any file.

Comment: This question is not about encrypting data in database; I want to find a secure way to process logins to my wcf servicel.

Comment: in case you do not want to make use of simple username and password login systems, Digital Signature is the best and most secure approach.